# Creating a Python type(class) with methods as callable objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

For example, if I do this for a `classmethod` everything goes as expected and the actual `cls` gets passed to the `X.__call___`:

```py
class X:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self)
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        print("Hi")

t = type("Y", (object,), dict(x=classmethod(X())))
ti = t()
ti.x()
```

Outputs

```
<__main__.X object at 0x7f835ec664c0>
(<class '__main__.Y'>,)
{}
Hi
```

But when I try to create a `Y` type with an `x` method as a regular one (non static) interpreter does not seem to pass the actual `Y` instance when executing `X.__call__`. For example:

```py
class X:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self)
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        print("Hi")

t = type("Y", (object,), dict(x=X()))
ti = t()
ti.x()
```

Outputs:

```
<__main__.X object at 0x7fdce385e4c0>
()
{}
Hi
```

Does anyone have an idea why isn't the instance of `Y` being passed, but in the case of a `classmethod` the `cls` argument is being passed? Thanks!

Comment: Because `classmethod` is explicitly a decorator overriding the behaviour of the first argument passed to the method. Without it, it's  just `X()()`, and you'd expect the instance of `X` to be passed as `self`, wouldn't you?

Comment: Nope, read the question again. I am expecting an Instance of dynamically created class Y to be passed to X.__call__ e.g. (self_x, self_y, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: I'm saying you'd expect `X()()` to receive an `X` instance as `self`, no? That's basically what you're doing in a roundabout way.

Comment: I don't think we are on the same page with this one. It's not the problem that I get an instance of a callable object (X) but that the actual call e.g.
 `ti.x()` is not implicitly passing the `ti` instance to `x()`. I would like to achieve this behavior without needing to do it like `ti.x(ti)`

Comment: Yeah, I get what you want. I'm just proposing an explanation why it *doesn't* do it. What to do to make it do what you want is a different story I haven't said anything about.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to also override the `__get__`. But again this is not the way I intended it to be, and there is a bit of overhead in **get**.

```py
class X:

    def __init__(self):
        self.holder = None

    def __get__(self, holder, holder_type):
        self.holder = holder
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self)
        print(self.holder)
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        print("Hi")

t = type("Y", (object,), dict(x=X()))
ti = t()
ti.x()
```